# Linear Regression in Open CV?

Tags: math, opencv, linear-regression

I am currently trying to determine the mean line of a 2D Point cloud ..
and while I am doing so, I asked myself whether there is a solution for this in OpenCV or not?
So that I just can push a vector with points and parameters to it and then get back the calculated mean-line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [fitLine](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fitline#fitline) function, it is based on weighted least-squares algorithm.

Comment: I have discovered that ´fitLine()´ does not do a linear regression as such. It really fit a line but using another method (LMS), so if you are going to compare your line with, for example, the line obtained through Excel, the result is different.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, FitLine requires the coordinates of all points used in the regression, which can be obtained using contours but this can be a convoluted process.